# Messy mouse events in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

In IE or Firefox the site works like this (IE11):
[image]
(Tabs are clickable)

but not in chrome. Click on tabs not get fired. I tried to reveal element in Developer Tools, but it reveals `#container` element instead of the `li`element I clicked on.

It looks like the layering of the elements are not the same as you see it and when you raise an event (ex.: click). The first/parent `div` is the top element and the tabs (`li`) are nested behind.

Why is it working in IE and Firefox, and why does not  in Chrome? What is the differecnce?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('flipped');
})

$('li').click(function() {
  var text = 'You selected ' + $(this).html();
  alert(text);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000);
  transition: all 300ms, transform 500ms ease;
}
.box figure {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: visibility 0s ease 140ms;
}
.box:not(.flipped) figure.back {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.box.flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.box .front {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.box .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.box .back .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.box .back .nav li {
  background-color: white;
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='box'>
    <figure class='front'>
      <p>FRONT SIDE</p>
    </figure>
    <figure class='back'>
      <ul class='nav'>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
      </ul>
      <div class='content'>
        <p>BACK SIDE</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<button>FLIP</button>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Only pressing minus button is not constructing at all! Please leave comment, how can I improve my question!

Comment: I didn't vote to close but it would help if you give the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour in a more descriptive way. Also see a [__Minimal__, __Complete__, and __Verifiable__ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [__Short__, __Self Contained__, Correct (__Compilable__) example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The expected behaviour is shown on the gif or you can test it in IE and Firefox with JSFiddle I attached. I tried to minimalize the code as much as I can. I did not want to remove dimenstions and background colors to keep it lifelike.

Comment: the JSfiddle is working in chrome for me. What version of chrome are you using. Mine is 37.0.2062.124 m

Comment: Mine is: 37.0.2062.120 m. Is just the flip thing or you can click the tabs also? (Menu1, Menu2 ...)

Comment: Ok, I updated it to .124 m and it still producing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem. If I set `z-index: 0` and `position: relative` to `body` and the `body > div` then clicks get fired.

**SOLUTION : CSS**

```
body, body > div { position: relative; z-index: 0; }
```

```js
$('button, .front').click(function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('flipped');
})

$('li').click(function() {
  var text = 'You selected ' + $(this).html();
  alert(text);
});
```

```css
/*Workaround*/

body,
body > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
/************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000);
  transition: all 300ms, transform 500ms ease;
}
.box figure {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: visibility 0s ease 140ms;
}
.box:not(.flipped) figure.back {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.box.flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.box .front {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.box .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.box .back .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.box .back .nav li {
  background-color: white;
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'>
    <figure class='front'>
      <p>FRONT SIDE</p>
    </figure>
    <figure class='back'>
      <ul class='nav'>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
      </ul>
      <div class='content'>
        <p>BACK SIDE</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<button>FLIP</button>
```

Comment: I run the JS Fiddle you provided on Chrome version "37.0.2062.124 m" and it's not working. If you fixed this issue, please share the code. Instead of using JSFiddle, you can use StackOverflow Code Snippet: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I replaced jsFiddle to internal viewer/editor.
It is working for me. 
The code I used: `body, body > div { position: relative; z-index: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% saint with your work, wrap your JS code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... })
```

Secondly I would not advise to use such big qualifiers $('li'). This will scan every list element in DOM tree-slow and not advised. Here you are interested in list elements from menu only.
I would also find Flip button by id, you have only one button, so it doesn't cost much:)

I would propose something like this :

```
var navContainer = $('.box > figure.back > ul.nav');
navContainer.on('click', 'li', function(){  ...  })
```

This code should work, even when you add more li items to DOM. 
Secondly you could in debug mode find, if this navContainer has been found or not.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your willingness to help.
The real code is not so simple. This is just an example to reproduce the issue.